# HTML thumbnail size issue

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrwrE.png)

I have an issue with thumbnail size. In the picture, there should have been another picture in white area in the left-middle, but the space is skipped because an image above has a long title. Everytime a picture with a long title is showed up, the size becomes larger. Is there any way I can fix thumbnail size even though the title gets longer?

Here is my HTML code and CSS i don't write anything.

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="recipeResults" class="row">
    <!-- templates/BasicImages/imageTemplates.js -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is actual code. Sorry :)

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="hovereffect">
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{{json.url}}" alt="{{json.alt_name}}">
        <div class="overlay">
           <h3> {{json.hoverDescription}}</h3>
           <a class="info" href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{json.cookTime}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="caption">
      <p style="font-size: 1pt;">&nbsp;</p>
      <h4>{{json.name}}</h4>
      <p>{{json.description}}</p>
      <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Save
        </button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not getting. can you give me your link?

Comment: Either you can set a fixed height for every separate block or just use a parent div for closing the three child divs.

Comment: Please provide us a link or source code

Comment: Use flex property of css

Comment: Please don't post question without any code. We aren't magicians who can read and solve the issue.

Comment: Here is html code. I don't know if that is helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for the box tag (or title tag) in CSS to prevent any over sizing

```css
.class-name{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[CSS overflow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using **Flex** you can align children of different height vertically without leaving gaps.

```
<div id="outer-wrap">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
div#outer-wrap {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100 vw;
}
div#outer-wrap .child {
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet or a fiddle of the issue.

Comment: I feel like I need to create and play with .thumbnail in css